# Как сконфигурировать client_max_body_size в nginx

Tags: nginx

Нужно изменить значение client_max_body_size в конфиг файле нгинкса (debian), добавляю в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf вначале файла

```
client_max_body_size 100m;
```

после чего ребут нгинкса - и как результат, нгинкс не стартует..

p.s. по умолчанию **client_max_body_size** отсутствует в конфиг файле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убедитесь, что директива в файле nginx.conf стоит внутри блока **http**, а не просто в начале файла

```
http {    client_max_body_size 16M;    # ...    server {        location {        }    }}
```

Comment: а может быть такое что client_max_body_size по умолчанию в конфиге отсутствует?

Comment: спасибо все ок!